# Interleaving multiple iterables randomly while preserving their order in python

Tags: python

Inspired by [this earlier stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644925/randomly-interleave-2-arrays-in-python) I have been considering how to randomly interleave iterables in python while preserving the order of elements within each iterable. For example:

```
>>> def interleave(*iterables):
...     "Return the source iterables randomly interleaved"
...     <insert magic here>
>>> interleave(xrange(1, 5), xrange(5, 10), xrange(10, 15))
[1, 5, 10, 11, 2, 6, 3, 12, 4, 13, 7, 14, 8, 9]
```

The original question asked to randomly interleave two lists, a and b, and the accepted solution was:

```
>>> c = [x.pop(0) for x in random.sample([a]*len(a) + [b]*len(b), len(a)+len(b))]
```

However, this solution works for only two lists (though it can easily be extended) and relies on the fact that a and b are lists so that `pop()` and `len()` can be called on them, meaning it cannot be used with iterables. It also has the unfortunate side effect of emptying the source lists a and b.

Alternate answers given for the original question take copies of the source lists to avoid modifying them, but this strikes me as inefficient, especially if the source lists are sizeable. The alternate answers also make use of `len()` and therefore cannot be used on mere iterables.

I wrote my own solution that works for any number of input lists and doesn't modify them:

```
def interleave(*args):
    iters = [i for i, b in ((iter(a), a) for a in args) for _ in xrange(len(b))]
    random.shuffle(iters)
    return map(next, iters)
```

but this solution also relies on the source arguments being lists so that `len()` can be used on them.

So, is there an efficient way to randomly interleave iterables in python, preserving the original order of elements, which doesn't require knowledge of the length of the iterables ahead of time and doesn't take copies of the iterables?

**Edit:** Please note that, as with the original question, I don't need the randomisation to be fair.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using a generator:

```
import random

def interleave(*args):
  iters = map(iter, args)
  while iters:
    it = random.choice(iters)
    try:
      yield next(it)
    except StopIteration:
      iters.remove(it)

print list(interleave(xrange(1, 5), xrange(5, 10), xrange(10, 15)))
```

Comment: +1, although the solution with `_stop` is not so nice. Maybe `try: val=...` \n `except StopIteration: iters.pop(i)` \n `else: yield val` would be cleaner.

Comment: @glglgl: I've been experimenting with various ways to phrase the generator. The version I've just edited into the answer is the one I like the most.

Comment: Nice answer. Note that using a try-except is about 15% slower than the equivalent solution without a try-except (when I tried it on CPython 2.7).

Answer (score 3):

Not if you want fit to be "fair".

Imagine you have a list containing one million items and another containing just two items. A "fair" randomization would have the first element from the short list occurring at about index 300000 or so.

```
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,...,a,a,a,b,a,a,a,....
                        ^
```

But there's no way to know in advance until you know the length of the lists.

If you just take from each list with 50% (1/n) probability then it can be done without knowing the lengths of the lists but you'll get something more like this:

```
a,a,b,a,b,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,...
    ^   ^
```

Comment: As with the original question, I don't need the randomisation to be fair. I would be happy with an "unfair" randomisation.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I appreciate that the fairness of the answer is an important consideration if one were doing this in a real world scenario. In this case, however, I wanted a merely random solution, so it is possible (and indeed must be possible) for the items from a short list to appear anywhere in the resultant list.

Comment: @srgerg: it's *possible* with both methods than an item from b could appear anywhere in the list. But the "fair" method makes it *likely*. It's *extremely* unlikely to get an element from b after index 100 with the method you've accepted, though I agree it's technically speaking not impossible.

Comment: Ahh, now I appreciate what you're saying fully. Excellent point!

Comment: I've added some comments in [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10662052/631586) to this question showing just how "unfair" a solution can be without knowing the length of its inputs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I am satisfied that the solution provided by aix meets the requirements of the question. However, after reading the [comments by Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10648380/631586) I wanted to see just how "unfair" the solution was.

Furthermore, sometime after I wrote this question, stack overflow user EOL posted [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10649247/631586) to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10644925/631586) which yields a "fair" result. EOL's solution is:

```
>>> a.reverse()
>>> b.reverse()
>>> [(a if random.randrange(0, len(a)+len(b)) < len(a) else b).pop()
...     for _ in xrange(len(a)+len(b))]
```

I also further enhanced my own solution so that it does not rely on its arguments supporting  `len()` but does make copies of the source iterables:

```
def interleave(*args):
    iters = sum(([iter(list_arg)]*len(list_arg) for list_arg in map(list, args)), [])
    random.shuffle(iters)
    return map(next, iters)
```

or, written differently:

```
def interleave(*args):
    iters = [i for i, j in ((iter(k), k) for k in map(list, args)) for _ in j]
    random.shuffle(iters)
    return map(next, iters)
```

I then tested the accepted solution to the original question, written by F.J and reproduced in my question above, to the solutions of aix, EOL and my own. The test involved interleaving a list of 30000 elements with a single element list (the sentinel). I repeated the test 1000 times and the following table shows, for each algorithm, the minimum, maximum and mean index of the sentinel after interleaving, along with the total time taken. We would expect a "fair" algorithm to produce a mean of approx. 15,000:

```
algo    min             max             mean            total_seconds
----    ---             ---             ----            -------------
F.J:    5               29952           14626.3         152.1
aix:    0               8               0.9             27.5
EOL:    45              29972           15091.0         61.2
srgerg: 23              29978           14961.6         18.6
```

As can be seen from the results, each of the algorithms of F.J, EOL and srgerg produce ostensibly "fair" results (at least under the given test conditions). However aix's algorithm has always placed the sentinel within the first 10 elements of the result. I repeated the experiment several times with similar results.

So Mark Byers is proved correct. If a truly random interleaving is desired, the length of the source iterables will need to be known ahead of time, or copies will need to be made so the length can be determined.

Comment: +1: Shuffling iterators is a neat idea! However, I wish the list comprehension expression were easier to read. I also added a more straightforward (and probably faster) version of your code.